# How to overlay an image

Tags: css, html, z-index

Im trying to overlay an image over two div col.'s - I tried using Z-index. And played around with as much positioning properties that I know.

What am I doing wrong. The triangle behind the two boxes, as well as the rest of the text you'll see in JSFiddle, should be on top of the radial-gradient[ed] box.

```css
#background-wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 25px;
    width: 1024px;
}


body {
background-color: #666;

}

body {
background-image: url("images/background-01.png");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-position: center;
}

.container-01 {
position: absolute;
margin: 50px 50px;
width: 380px;
height: 160px;
opacity: .65;
background: #555; /* For browsers that do not support gradients */
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(circle, black, grey, white); /* Safari */
  background: -o-radial-gradient(circle,  black, grey, white); /* Opera 11.6 to 12.0 */
  background: -moz-radial-gradient(circle,  black, grey, white); /* Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
  background: radial-gradient(circle,  black, grey, white); /* Standard syntax */
z-index: 1

}
    

}

#trident {
clear: both;
left: 50px;
z-index: 2;
}


.container-01-box {
position: relative;
margin: 60px 60px;
width: 360px;
height: 140px;
    
background: #555; /* For browsers that do not support gradients */
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(circle, black, grey, white); /* Safari */
  background: -o-radial-gradient(circle,  black, grey, white); /* Opera 11.6 to 12.0 */
  background: -moz-radial-gradient(circle,  black, grey, white); /* Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
  background: radial-gradient(circle,  black, grey, white); /* Standard syntax */

z-index: 1
}
```

```html
<title>UNAWAKENED.NET - Welcome!</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
    


</head>




<body>
<section id="background-wrapper">

    
    <header>_</header>
<div class="container-01"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c1/Penrose-dreieck.svg/526px-Penrose-dreieck.svg.png" id="trident" alt="Triangle" width="100"><h1 id="top-box">Featured Dream</h1></div>
    <div class="container-01-box"><h1 id="name-of-dream">"The ships from Nova"</h1></div>
</body>
```

It's for unawakened.net if anyone is curious. Please explain the logic if you found an answer by the way!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: r u looking like this? http://jsfiddle.net/sureshponnukalai/e73ys781/

Comment: almost. Im gonna inspect your code. But I want the elements to be above the boxes entirely. Without blending.

Ill look into it, what did you do though? :)

Comment: I just changed the `z-index:1` to `z-index:100` for the `container-01` class

Comment: oic thanks - problem solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
#background-wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 25px;
    width: 1024px;
}


body {
background-color: #666;

}

body {
background-image: url("images/background-01.png");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-position: center;
}

.container-01 {
position: absolute;
margin: 50px 50px;
width: 380px;
height: 160px;
opacity: .65;
background: #555; /* For browsers that do not support gradients */
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(circle, black, grey, white); /* Safari */
  background: -o-radial-gradient(circle,  black, grey, white); /* Opera 11.6 to 12.0 */
  background: -moz-radial-gradient(circle,  black, grey, white); /* Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
  background: radial-gradient(circle,  black, grey, white); /* Standard syntax */
z-index: 2

}
    

}

#trident {
clear: both;
left: 50px;
z-index: 2;
}


.container-01-box {
position: relative;
margin: 60px 60px;
width: 360px;
height: 140px;
    
background: #555; /* For browsers that do not support gradients */
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(circle, black, grey, white); /* Safari */
  background: -o-radial-gradient(circle,  black, grey, white); /* Opera 11.6 to 12.0 */
  background: -moz-radial-gradient(circle,  black, grey, white); /* Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
  background: radial-gradient(circle,  black, grey, white); /* Standard syntax */

z-index: 1
}
```

```html
<title>UNAWAKENED.NET - Welcome!</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
    


</head>




<body>
<section id="background-wrapper">

    
    <header>_</header>
<div class="container-01"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c1/Penrose-dreieck.svg/526px-Penrose-dreieck.svg.png" id="trident" alt="Triangle" width="100"><h1 id="top-box">Featured Dream</h1></div>
    <div class="container-01-box"><h1 id="name-of-dream">"The ships from Nova"</h1></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to Image stay on Top then you have to keep separate div for IMG and keep Z-index larger than other two. please try or can you please share the images that how it will look. :)

Comment: It just took me some time to figure out using z-index for the first time. Thanks